# Django server side AJAX validation

Tags: ajax, django

Recently I'm trying to implement a simple Django application that include one server side AJAX validation, it's a simple form input field (username). I have used a pre-built in line AJAX validation library which uses jQuery. So the code goes like this

**HTML snippet**

```
<form id="simpleform" method="post" action="/done/">

Username:<input value="" class="validate[required,custom[noSpecialCaracters],length[0,20],ajax[ajaxUser]]" type="text" name="user" id="user" />

<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Validate"/>
</form>
```

**The server side code snippet (embedded in to a php script)**

```
/* RECEIVE VALUE */
$validateValue=$_POST['validateValue'];
$validateId=$_POST['validateId'];
$validateError=$_POST['validateError'];

    /* RETURN VALUE */
    $arrayToJs = array();
    $arrayToJs[0] = $validateId;
    $arrayToJs[1] = $validateError;

if($validateValue =="testname"){        // validate??
    $arrayToJs[2] = "true";         // RETURN TRUE
    echo '{"jsonValidateReturn":'.json_encode($arrayToJs).'}';          // RETURN ARRAY WITH success
}else{
    for($x=0;$x<1000000;$x++){
        if($x == 990000){
            $arrayToJs[2] = "false";
            echo '{"jsonValidateReturn":'.json_encode($arrayToJs).'}';      // RETURN ARRAY WITH ERROR
        }
    }

}
```

So my question is that how do I get this in to Python code (in order to use in Django environment) how do I get the user name from the input field in to the back end,I think the server side script snippet already does it but I want to know how to use this in my Pyhon code,and this is my first time using jQuery and I do need to use this same exact validation library. Your valuable corporation is needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your HTML snippet is not good at all. Simply you cannot give to a `class` a value of `validate[required,custom[noSpecialCaracters],length[0,20],ajax[ajaxUser]]` because this violates the w3c standards.

Second you can't just use the exact same validation system because here is Django and Python and that means totally different system with a lot better validation process than the pure php you provided. So i'm suggesting you, to think a different way to do what you want especially the long value you assigning in `class` (!) which is not seems to be a css valid class. I'm suggesting you to use `hidden` fields instead.

Although here is a starting point for you:

HTML Template, **index.html**

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        {{ form.errors }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
<form id="simpleform" method="post" action="/done/">
    <label for="{{ form.username.name }}">{{ form.username.label }}</label>
    {{ form.username }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button id="submit" class="submit" type="submit">Validate</button>
</form>
```

**forms.py**. Just create this file inside your app folder

```
from django import forms
class SimpleForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username:", max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'username', 'class':'css-class-name', 'data-validation':'validate[required,custom[noSpecialCaracters],length[0,20],ajax[ajaxUser]]'}))
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .forms import SimpleForm

@csrf_exempt
def validate(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        form = SimpleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #Do something when the form is valid...

            response_data = { 'username':form.cleaned_data['username'] }
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data), mimetype="application/json")
    else:
        form = SimpleForm()

    template = {
        'form':form
        }

    return render(request, 'index.html', template)
```

Your **urls.py** should look like this.  is the name of the folder where *views.py* is living.

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^done/$', 'appname.views.validate', name='validate'),
)
```

In your JQuery code you should processing the `data-validation` attribute with JQuery's [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

To handle AJAX check JQuery's [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method. A short example is this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/done/',
    data: {username: get_username_here},
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        //Do something before send...
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('Ajax success: ' + data.username);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + '. ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do just like you did, django views receives a request parameter. The request parameter  has a POST "dictionary".

```
def validate(request):
    print request.POST["validateValue"]
    ...
```

Comment: Yes we can get request parameters, but in this case it's not a request parameter, I'm searching for a solution that can embed server side script (javascript) in to my view so then I can easily retun json value to the client side.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly offtopic, but from my experience it's best to do server side AJAX validation in exactly the same way as regular form validation on submit - this gives exactly the same error messages, if any, by using exactly the same validation code - and therefore provides consistent [Hijax-compliant](http://www.google.com/search?q=hijax) user experience.

Answer (score -1):

have a look [at the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Comment: Thanks but I have looked at it earlier, didn't find what I need.

Comment: then have another look behind my link. this is exactly what you are looking for....